# Is there a practical security difference between OTP with letters and OTP with numbers?

Tags: one-time-pad, encoding, frequency-analysis

Is there a practical security difference between *“OTP with letters”* and *“OTP with numbers”*?

If, for example, I encrypt a letter message using Tabula Recta with a random letter key, I would get:

```
THISI SATES TXAAA - message
MOSSK VFXNN EJRQW - OTP key
FVAKS NFQRF XGRQW - cipher
```

Would such encryption be less secure when it comes to frequency analysis, compared to (let's say) Dirk Rijmenant's CT-46 OTP where the most frequent letters (`AEINOR`) are associated with a single digit instead of two digits, like the rest of the less frequent letters in the alphabet?

Example:

```
THISI SATES TXAAA 
83753 82390 82183 28290 83871 11000 - message
08733 64840 36236 58407 58482 94160 - OTP key
85020 28550 56957 70893 35499 27940 - cipher
```

Comment: No, OTP has perfect secrecy regardless of what encoding your message uses.

Comment: Hint: Can you find an OTP key(part) that maps an arbitrary cipher text to an arbitrary plain text. Or formulated differently: Can every cipher text letter be decrypted to every plain text letter if an appropriate OTP is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no security difference. Of course, purely random characters with entropy rate $\log M$ where $M$ is the size of the alphabet should be independently generated and used for the OTP, whatever the size $M$ of the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Letters only allow you to use letters and nothing else.

So you would only be able to send a message like this:

```
MEETA GENTV LADAT DINER ATTWO
```

Where as if you use numbers you can send messages with virtually all the different characters you want:

```
Meet Agent Vlad at diner at 2.
```

Comment: Yes; but the question asks for "a practical _security_ difference".

Comment: Of course. Provided that ALL of the rules regarding OTPs are followed to the letter with NO shortcuts, it matters not what you use. On that note there is a ASCII Armor scheme called Codegroup that allows you to convert binary data into 5 letter groups. So if you were to encode your data with that and then apply the Letters OTP then you could solve that problem.

Comment: I have to agree with  @fgrieu. This doesn’t really seem answer the question. You provide an example of the difference in encoding when using both, which is nice… but what is the *“practical **security** difference”*? Or are we simply not understanding you and you are pointing to some security difference between writing `two` and `2`? If, it would probably be constructive to help us understand your answer by describing whatever difference in security you see there.

Comment: I am simply stating that it is much more practical to use numbers to encode OTP messages which I like to call Numbers Messages because of the fact that you have more flexibility and messages can also be shrunk by using a code book as well. So in the unlikely event that a pad is compromised there is still one more layer of security. Even if it is weaker.